# How do I read in 2 different objects to 2 different ArrayList from the same file?

Tags: java

I am reading in a binary file which contains 2 different kinds of objects such as HP and Dell.  The super class would be computers and I want to ready in HP and Dell to their own ArrayList. I would like to know how I could do this where I call the readFile() method once, and put them into a public ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Call `readFile` once to read data from your file into a variable. Now you can operate on the data as many times as you need without having to read from the file again.